# "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal" in JS when passed data to view

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I am tryind send data from database table to CKEDITOR. Data are send to view (Blade) in `$page` variable. In `$page->body` is `<p>Example text</p>`
I use JavaScript to display data in CKEDITOR:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.instances.messageArea.setData("{!! $page->body !!}");
</script>
```

but error appeares:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
CKEDITOR.instances.messageArea.setData("<p>Example text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$page->body` seems to contain line breaks, but javascript strings don't support line breaks. You can try a template string instead:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.messageArea.setData(`{!! $page->body !!}`);
```